# SQL Server : Identity column by group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqltransaction

How can I add an identity number so that when a row is inserted an incremental number is assigned as below by a trigger? I am using SQL Server.

```
1    AAA  
2    AAA  
3    BBB  
4    CCC  
5    CCC  
6    CCC  
7    DDD  
8    DDD  
9    EEE  
....
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
1    AAA   1
2    AAA   2
4    CCC   1
5    CCC   2
6    CCC   3
7    DDD   1
8    DDD   2
```

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: MS SQL database

Comment: Do you also want to filter out the rows with id 3 and 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `FUNCTION` which get a name and gives `MAX` identity for given parameter:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetIdentityForName] (@Name VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS INT
AS
  BEGIN
      RETURN
        (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(NameId),0)+1
         FROM  YourTable
         WHERE Name = @Name);
  END
```

and then set `DefaultValue` for `NameId` for call the function when a record has been inserted like this:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD CONSTRAINT
    DF_Identity_NameId DEFAULT ([dbo].[GetIdentityForName](Name)) FOR NameId
```

Assuming that `YourTable` is (`Id`, `Name`, `NameId`).

I hope to be helpful for you :)

Comment: is it possible to get the answer in same table ?

Comment: You means get the results as `Query` without changing table definition?

Comment: i am getting this error when i put it into same table Error Message: Maximum stored procedure , function , trigger or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

Comment: This doesn't work. I get "The column 'Name' is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted." when attempting to add the default constraint

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason why you have to store the value.  You could calculate it when you need it:

```
select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as nameId
from t;
```

Comment: In this solution, if a row is deleted, the row_numbers of the remaining rows change. That might be a reason to store the value.